# Sound design software for Linux?

Tags: software, linux

Any recommended sound design software for Linux? It doesnt have to be open source or free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure Data                       .

Answer (score 2):

**[Audacity](http://audacityteam.org/)**

> Audacity® is free, open source, cross-platform software for recording
> and editing sounds (comparable to software like Sound Forge and Wave Lab, only somewhat simpler).
>
> Audacity is available for Windows®, Mac®, GNU/Linux®; and other
> operating systems.

**[Ardour](http://ardour.org/)**

> Professional-grade multitrack/multichannel hard-disk recording/DAW:
> Record, edit, mix and master audio and MIDI projects.
>
> Comparable to software like Pro Tools, Cubase and Logic.

**Additional software**

For an extensive list of audio related software for linux see:

http://wiki.linuxaudio.org/apps/daw_apps

Answer (score 1):

While not free (as in beer or freedom) if you want a fully-fledged DAW there's also [Bitwig Studio](http://www.bitwig.com/en.html) which is available on Linux, Windows, and OS X.

[image: Bitwig Studio Screenshot]

There's even a free demo available on their website which only has the limitation of not being able to save your projects. (If you're not using Ubuntu, check your repos. For instance Arch has it in the AUR)

Note that I do not work for Bitwig, I just really enjoy using it. =)